# Select list of entries with Group BY in EF Core C3

Tags: c#, asp.net, group-by, entity-framework-core

```
var response = await _db.Transaction
                        .Where(expression)
                        .OrderBy(x => x.AmountSqft)
                        .GroupBy(x => new { CityName = x.City.Name, CityNameAr = x.City.NameAr })
                        .Select(x => new SalesTrendDTO
                                         {
                                             Label = x.Key.CityName,
                                             LabelAr = x.Key.CityNameAr,
                                             ListAvgPricePerSqft = x.Select(z => z.AmountSqft).ToList()
                                         }).ToListAsync();
```

I have this group by clause in my repository. I want to select list of decimal along with key of group by is there any way to select. I want to take Median of that list rather that using built-in linq Average method.

```
response = await _db.Transaction
                    .Where(expression)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.AmountSqft)
                    .GroupBy(x => new { CityName = x.City.Name, CityNameAr = x.City.NameAr })
                    .Select(x => new SalesTrendDTO
                                 {
                                     Label = x.Key.CityName,
                                     LabelAr = x.Key.CityNameAr,
                                     ListAvgPricePerSqft = x.Select(z => z.AmountSqft).ToList()
                                 }).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean calling the C# method for averaging, it is not possible. For this, you need to call SQL Native. Also, put the sort in the internal list in the above query.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).